# pass mysql column to php function variable

Tags: php, mysql, function

I'd like to know ,How to pass mysql table columns in php variable function like 
 this example

```
<?php
 function multi($type){
 return $type*5;
 }
$sql="INSERT INTO table_a (column_a) select '".multi(column_b)."' from table_b"
 ?>
```

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: `Sql="` is that a typo with the missing `$` sign? you also didn't close that statement. If this is pseudo code, you need to use a proper example. The missing `$` would automatically throw an undefined constant warning.

Comment: sorry ,that's typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't invoke PHP operations from mysql (not strictly true, but we're talking about building a whole new PHP SAPI and a complex MySQL UDF or engine - months of work for someone who already has expertise in these things).

The most efficient solution would be to implement your function in MySQL. With the example you provided:

```
DELIMITER $$;

CREATE function multi(itype int) 
RETURNS int
BEGIN
    return itype*5;
END
$$

INSERT INTO table_a (column_a) 
SELECT multi(column_b) FROM table_b
$$
```

But presumably you want to do something more complex than multiply by 5. Assuming that this cannot be done in MySQL, then you need to pull the data into PHP and create INSERT statements from there:

```
$res=mysqli_query($dbh, "SELECT column_b FROM table_b");
while ($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $ins="INSERT INTO table_a(column_a) VALUES ("
        . multi($r['column_b']) , ");";
    if (!mysqli_query($dbh, $ins)) {
        die mysqli_error($dbh);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank a lot, it's very helpfull

Answer (score 0):

At first step you should have a connection with database in your code like this:

```
$db=mysqli_connect("database address","username","password","database_name");
```

Then you should run your query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, {your_query_as_string});
```

then you can use each row of result like this:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

each time you run this  `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);` , the `row` variable is standing for each rows.
this example will show you to use all rows:
`while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) { $name = $row['name']; }`

each `while cycle` will set `name` variable to each name column in your database. and when you reach the last value. the while will be exited.